# Git with one master and multiple child projects

Tags: git

I'm going to start a project where i'll develop a WordPress theme that is going to be a sort of framework for all my other projects.

I would like to create a 'master' Git project. Next to this project i'll start multiple 'child' projects that are pulled from the master. When i find a bug in one of the child projects i would like to fix this and push this back into the master project and than the master should push it to the all the child projects so the bug will be gone everywhere. I also want to make file modifications, but when i pull the master back into the child project, these file modifications shouldn't be overwritten. The whole idea behind this is to simply roll out new projects based on the framework that will always keep the projects up to date with the latest version of the framework.

Does anyone know how this could be solved?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really on topic at StackOverflow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're describing is that you want to establish your framework in one repo and then create forks from that repo for each of your project repos.

You can then add a remote to each of your projects to your upstream repo in order to pull updates from it.

One thing I would suggest though is that you make any changes or bug fixes on your framework repo to avoid accidentally including work from any of your projects in your framework by mistake.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the advice I was looking for :-)

Comment: No problem, glad to help :).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create each "child project" as a completely separate git repository. You should create "releases" from the template project just as you would for others to use it. Then this release can be used in each of the child projects. This will help you avoid accidentally committing changes to the template in one of the child projects.